# Local outlook & OWA Signatures

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, office365

I have an Office 365 account and I applied an HTML signature in my Office365 account.

In my local I configured my Outlook with this Office 365 account. When ever I send email from my local Outlook it is not considering signatures from Office 365.

Is there any possibility to apply the same signature on my local Outlook as well? If I changed the signature in my Office365 account the same signature should apply to my local Outlook.

Presently I am trying this C# code.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pasd);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(user, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

service.TraceEnabled = true;
Folder Root = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Root);
UserConfiguration OWAConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "OWA.UserOptions", Root.ParentFolderId, UserConfigurationProperties.All);
hsHtmlSigniture = div;
String stTextSig = "Text sig";


if (OWAConfig.Dictionary.ContainsKey("signaturehtml"))
{
    OWAConfig.Dictionary["signaturehtml"] = hsHtmlSigniture;
}
else
{
    OWAConfig.Dictionary.Add("signaturehtml", hsHtmlSigniture);
}
if (OWAConfig.Dictionary.ContainsKey("signaturetext"))
{
    OWAConfig.Dictionary["signaturetext"] = stTextSig;
}
else
{
    OWAConfig.Dictionary.Add("signaturetext", stTextSig);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix some grammar mistakes. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Signature applied in Office 365, will be applicable to email sent via OWA and Mobile app. It wont be applied to Outlook.